# React TypeScript: Argument is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My Router has a `useReducer` and the initialState has the error `Argument of type 'StateInterface' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.` this only started happening when I use `action.value` in the reducer in globalState.tsx

```
(Router.tsx)

    import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Layout } from './components/layout';
    import { Dispatch, Global, InitialState, Reducer } from './globalState';
    import { Home } from './routes/home';
    import { NotFound } from './routes/notFound';

    const Router: React.FC = () => {
      const [global, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, InitialState); //<==== Here is the error
      return (
        <Dispatch.Provider value={{ dispatch }}>
          <Global.Provider value={{ global }}>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Route
                render={({ location }) => (
                  <Layout location={location}>
                    <Switch location={location}>
                      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                      <Route component={NotFound} />
                    </Switch>
                  </Layout>
                )}
              />
            </BrowserRouter>
          </Global.Provider>
        </Dispatch.Provider>
      );
    };

    export { Router };
```

then global state looks like

```
(globalState.tsx)

    import { createContext } from 'react';

    interface StateInterface {
      warningMessage: string;
      warningShow: boolean;
    }

    interface ActionInterface {
      type: string;
      value: string | boolean;
    }

    const Dispatch = createContext({
      dispatch: (action: ActionInterface) => {
        //
      },
    });

    const InitialState: StateInterface = {
      warningMessage: '',
      warningShow: false,
    };

    const Global = createContext({
      global: InitialState,
    });

    const WARNING_TOGGLE = 'WARNING_TOGGLE';
    const WARNING_MESSAGE = 'WARNING_MESSAGE';

    const Reducer = (state: StateInterface, action: ActionInterface) => { // <= if I change ActionInterface to any the probem goes away, but my linter then fires of with no any allowed
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'WARNING_TOGGLE':
          return {
            ...state,
            warningShow: action.value, // <== If I remove `action.value and set this to `true` the error goes away
          };
        case 'WARNING_MESSAGE':
          return {
            ...state,
            warningMessage: action.value, // <== If I remove `action.value and set this to `some string` the error goes away
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };

    export { Reducer, InitialState, Dispatch, Global, WARNING_TOGGLE, WARNING_MESSAGE };
```

and Home

```
(home.tsx)

    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import { Dispatch, Global, WARNING_MESSAGE, WARNING_TOGGLE} from '../globalState';

    const Home: React.FC = () => {
      const { global } = useContext(Global);
      const { dispatch } = useContext(Dispatch);

      const openWarning = () => {
        dispatch({ type: WARNING_TOGGLE, value: true});
      };

      const closeWarning = () => {
        dispatch({ type: WARNING_TOGGLE, value: false});
      };

      const warningMessageVerify = () => {
        dispatch({ type: WARNING_MESSAGE, value: 'Please verify your email'});
      };

      const warningMessageOffine = () => {
        dispatch({ type: WARNING_MESSAGE, value: 'You are now offline'});
      };
      return (
      <section>
      {global.warningShow && <div>Warning Open</div>}
      {!global.warningShow && <div>Warning Closed</div>}
      {global.warningMessage}
      <br/>
        <button onClick={openWarning}>Open Warning</button>
        <button onClick={closeWarning}>Close Warning</button>
        <button onClick={warningMessageVerify}>Verify Email</button>
        <button onClick={warningMessageOffine}>Offline</button>
      </section>
      );
    };

    export { Home };
```

Comment: Not a typescript expert, but still Can you check what is the typeof InitialState and ActionInterface? And see if the type matches here,
```(globalState.tsx)

const Reducer = (state: StateInterface, action: ActionInterface)
```

Comment: `console.log(typeof InitialState);` returns Object

Answer (score 8):

Typescript is not able to determine a safe typecast from `IActionInterface` `value: string | boolean` to `StateInterface` `warningShow: boolean`, in this code - `warningShow: action.value`. It cannot safely presume that `value` will only contain a boolean.

There are several ways to suppress this, a simple one is -

`warningShow: action.value as boolean`

`warningMessage: action.value as string`

The `as` keyword will assert that the type of `value` is a `boolean` or `string`.

Comment: +1 This is the reason why we should not try to reuse a single interface for different actions. It is not going to be shipped anyway.

Comment: That's definitely better than using a union. The typecasting would still be needed I guess.

Answer (score 3):

it is a best practice to define types for action creators separately.

Instead of

```
interface ActionInterface {
   type: string;
   value: string | boolean;
}
```

use two interface and define the type based on that

```
interface IActionInterface {
    type: string;
}

interface IMessageActionInterface extends IActionInterface { 
    value: string;
}

interface IShowActionInterface extends IActionInterface {
   value: boolean;
}

type ActionTypes = IMessageActionInterface | IShowActionInterface;
```

In Reducer

```
const Reducer = (state: StateInterface, action: ActionTypes) => { }
```

Comment: I think this is the right approach but then you are missing the literal type as the `type` property

Answer (score 0):

This seems odd in that if you do not explicitly return something from an arrow function. I believe that is construed as a "never". So, to me, this seems like the problem. If I am wrong, sorry about that.

```
const Dispatch = createContext({
  dispatch: (action: ActionInterface) => {
    //
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is related to the way you constructed your `ActionInterface` type and used it in the reducer.

What you need is to have a way for TypeScript to differentiate the action structure when you pass it to the switch statement.

The best way to solve this is by simply give a hint to TypeScript about your actions and the union type you have.

Look at this example in [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYElXAgJwGYCGcEAPACpQQAe2qAJgM5QPA6KoDmANFAKoB8UALxQA3gCgoUqKEgAuKGQDck6QDcCAGwCuEBbxUBfceLhoWUAOowASgDl0dgOIB9MgHknTgDIBRYVAA5Nb2jq4eXn6BKmaoFiEOzi4Asr4AymkwTv4iwbaJrqkZWb7RJrLQMJqa8EjmwqpStSgYWLiExCR5oUkRPqU8AEbIyJoQBKj8jVAAPrAILZjY%20ESk3QUp6ZnZgTwsbJz8KqbmwFA4EHTaxDgBABREdagKVTUL5gCUwoKiUAD0fygmDwuAgqGIdCgZhwFwQmhAUAITBI%203YHFmUGGo3Gk2mDAA7ohgHAABZQB7vVAAOgqXwk0gZUKR0ASYTcnn6cmmjOkF2A2hwqERlKpGh0ECU-0BWLGE250jgzKs%20TZRW2vi5PJ5fIFQseLVFWl0koBzFYaPlUjoEEI2k0wE1WoZOsFQUC02MxiAA)